# Do python codes need to be changed moving from ArcGIS 10.2 to 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

What changes (if any) do I need to make to my python scripts to migrate from ArcGIS10.2 to ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/94422

Comment: That's a pretty broad question, since there's no way to tell where and when some parameters to some functions have been changed.

Comment: Fair point @Vince, are there any big changes that one needs to be aware of? E.g. moving from ArcGIS 9.3 to ArcGIS 10 involved making changes (small and big) to quite  afew geoprocessing calls.

Comment: 10.3 from 10.2 has tiny ArcPy changes compared to 10.0 from 9.3.

Comment: thanks! this is good to know. are you aware of any page that lists these changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule we (esri) have when moving from version to version is **dont break backwards compatibility**. This means that a script written in an old version *should* run in a newer version.

Generally you can see items that have changed by looking in the [Whats new](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/main/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-1031.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_097098A85BE84E878CC3F27AC8AE6096) for a given release. You'll notice that with all the tool changes parameters have either been updated with new options, or new parameters have been appended to the end. This means your script will continue to run. You do not need to modify anything to take these changes into account.

You mentioned the difference between 9.3 and 10. Yes, the arcpy module was added then. However old scripts that still used arcgisscripting did and still do continue to work.

I'll stop short of saying there has never been or never will be a change that breaks something. But I honestly can't come up with anything off the top of my head. In conclusion, your script you have today should continue to work just fine in the upgrade.

(This post doesn't count for moving from 10.x to Pro where the versions of Python different and somethings in Python are **not** backwards compatible. There is also changes to arcpy.mapping. Everything that did change and you need to be updated is documented in the Pro migration help)

(Edit) Per the couple comments on things that have changed: I cannot offer a reason why, my best guess was a bug was logged to change the behavior of a specific item. If something wasn't working the way it was intended and was causing an issue, we'd fix it (so I guess that serves as an example where we wouldn't gauaranteed backwards compatibility). Something we wouldn't do (as a far out example) would be to change the parameter order just 'because'.

Comment: Well, between 10.0 and 10.1 there were some little changes that caused problems, like in 10.0 multi-input parameters resulted in a ValueTable object and in 10.1 they create list objects.  ValueTables and lists are iterated in a different fashion, so that's one example of a version upgrade completely breaking a script tool interface.  (List are the better choice anyway, so it's an improvement, but it's not backward compatible.)

Comment: Between 10.0 and 10.1 the output column of Raster to Polygon changed from [Grid_code](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000) to [Gridcode](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_to_Polygon/001200000008000000/).  That made porting a departed colleague's ArcObjects Java app a joy to behold.  It is true that backwards compatibility is preserved in most cases (which makes the exceptions stand out, unfortunately)